# One line definition of a symbol with plus-minus

Tags: custom-notation

I'm pretty new to Mathematica. I was wondering is there any way to define the symbol $H_\pm(x,y) = f(x) \pm g(y)$ in one line, so that $H_-$ or $H_+$ can be called separately? Something like: `H_-[1,2] = f[1] - g[2]` and `H_+[1,2] = f[1] + g[2]` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear[H]

H[s_][x_, y_] := 
 f[x] + Piecewise[{{-1, s === "-"}}, 1]*g[y] /; s === "+" || s === "-"
```

Examples:

```
{H["+"][x, y], H["-"][x, y]}

(*  {f[x] + g[y], f[x] - g[y]}  *)
```

Or

```
Clear[H]

H[s_][x_, y_] := f[x] + Sign[s]*g[y] /; Abs[s] === 1
```

Examples:

```
{H[1][x, y], H[-1][x, y]}

(*  {f[x] + g[y], f[x] - g[y]}  *)
```

Answer (score 9):

The most robust way I know of would be to use the built in [`Notation` package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) and write something like

```
Needs["Notation´"]

Symbolize[H±]  (* Be careful to use the Writing Assistant palette or other formatting guides s.t. the definition actually displays like you want it to and not Subscript or similar means *)

H±[x_, y_] := f[x] ± g[y] (* Same caveat about typesetting applies here as well *)
```

Then you get

```
In[1] := H±[1,2]
Out[1]:= f[1]±g[2]
```

In Mathematica it should look like this:

[image: Notation´ and Symbolize in action.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please see the edit in the question.

Comment: Defining the symbols should work analogously to my answer, or do you want to define both of them in one expression?

Comment: Yeah I want to define both of them in one line. Because I have two really huge expression where things differ by plus-minus only, so I am looking for a compact way of writing both of them in one shot.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version that allows you to use $H_+$ and $H_-$ as requested:

```
(h:SubPlus|SubMinus)[H] ^:= With[
    {hh=Replace[h, {SubPlus->Plus, SubMinus->Subtract}]},
    hh[f[#1], g[#2]]&
]
```

A couple examples:

```
SubPlus[H][x, y]
SubMinus[H][2, 3]
```

> f[x] + g[y]
>
> f[2] - g[3]

This is how the above appears in a notebook:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation on @Bob Hanlon's answer that uses functions instead of strings or integers.

```
h[op_Symbol][x_, y_] := op[f[x], g[y]]
```

This will work on any function that takes two or more arguments: `Plus`, `Subtract`, `Times`, `Divide`, `Union`, `Intersection`, and so on.

```
{h[Plus][m, n], h[Subtract][m, n], h[Times][m, n]}
(* {f[m] + g[n], f[m] - g[n], f[m] g[n]} *)
```

It can be restricted to just `Plus` and `Subtract` with `MemberQ`.

```
k[op_Symbol /; MemberQ[{Plus, Subtract}, op]][x_, y_] := op[f[x], g[y]]
```

`k` will only work for `Plus` and `Subtract`. For example, `Times` will not evaluate.

```
{k[Plus][m, n], k[Subtract][m, n], k[Times][m, n]}
(* {f[m] + g[n], f[m] - g[n], k[Times][m, n]} *)
```

Hope this helps.